# Joomla Component Creator table within a table

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

I have created a joomla component with [Joomla Component Creator](http://www.component-creator.com). 
It has two tables. The first table have a `jText` field called `emne` (subject). The second table have foregin key field called `emneid` (subjectid) so i can choose a subject from the first table. The second table also have `jText` field called title and download.

I have installed it and everything works fine in the admin panel.

It is the frontend where i have problems.

I want to view all the items from the second table within the item it belongs to from the first table.

Here is a link to the component:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_U9YUqXcmrEfm9PVUhkMkJrWEszc2pGZVE4cnhsdWZYRHpwV2UycUh4Q3IzalJoMWZ5d0k&usp=sharing

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little. What code do you have now? What exactly would you like to show on the front end. Sounds like you will need to edit your model and create an SQL join.

Comment: I fixed it.. i just read up on the joomla documentation for database calls. I just wondered if you could view both content from both tables in the same view/frontend from the settings in http://www.component-creator.com/.

Comment: The component creator will fetch some of the information from a linked table into the model of the first table. You can expand this functionality by editing the getItems - function of the model (models/emner.php), and also make sure this is displayed in the view views/emner/tmpl/default.php.